# Input field separator in awk

Tags: unix, regex, awk

I have many large data files. The delimiter between the fields is a semicolon. However, I have found that there are semicolons in some of the fields, so I cannot simply use the semicolon as a field separator.

The following example has 4 fields, but awk sees only 3, because the '1' in field 3 is stripped by the regex (which includes a '-' because some of the numerical data are negative):

```
echo '"This";"is";1;"line of; data"' | awk -F'[0-9"-];[0-9"-]' '{print "No. of fields:\t"NF; print "Field 3:\t" $3}'
No. of fields:  3
Field 3:        ;"line of; data"
```

Of course,

```
echo '"This";"is";1;"line of; data"' | awk -F';' '{print "No. of fields:\t"NF}'
No. of fields:  5
```

solves that problem, but counts the last field as two separate fields.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Thanks!

Matthijs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `GNU awk` and [`FPAT`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Splitting-By-Content.html):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FPAT = "([^;]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }'
```

Testing:

```
echo '"This";"is";1;"line of; data"' | awk 'BEGIN { FPAT = "([^;]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")" } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print $i }'
```

Results:

```
"This"
"is"
1
"line of; data"
```

Comment: +1 nice answer. I was just about to suggest using a different language with a CSV module.